# R-gwidgets- warning message

Tags: r, warnings, gwidgets

I'm using the package `gWidgetsRGtk2` to create a GUI that can manipulate a df. I never worked with this package before so I'm not an expert. When I try to make a window using gwindow everything works fine

```
gwindow("test")
guiWidget of type: gWindowRGtk for toolkit: guiWidgetsToolkitRGtk2
```

but when I try to make a function and asign the `gwindow()` (or `glabel`, `gbutton`, etc.) to a variable win, a get the following warning message:

> win=gwindow()
>    Warning in str.default(val) : 'str.default': 'le' is NA, so taken as 0
>    Warning in str.default(obj, ...) :
>    str.default': 'le' is NA, so taken as 0

When I try to get the corresponding selected value using `svalue()`, I get the following error:

> Error: attempt to call 'getText' on invalid reference 'obj@widget'

I have no idea how to solve this problem and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A couple things: First you should use `gWidgets2` and not `gWidgets`. The difference is small and the `gWidgets2` is easier to fix bugs. (Also the data frame stuff is better.) Second, the error comes from not passing in a title. Try `gwindow("some title")` and see if it goes away.